# .signInWithEmailandPassword is not a function

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I was following this video from the Firebase Team to add Firebase Auth to my application (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-OKrloDzGpU)

I have added the web application script generated for my project in Firebase into the html section of my app and basically copied the other code to do the login and signing up as seen in the code below

But I got this error which I have no idea why its triggering

TypeError: auth.signInWithEmailandPassword is not a function. (In 'auth.signInWithEmailandPassword(email, pass)', 'auth.signInWithEmailandPassword' is undefined)

## HTML Code

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <meta charset="utf-8" />


<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.7.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.7.0/firebase-auth.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" />
  </head>

  <body>

    <div class="container">
      <input id="txtEmail" type="email" required placeholder="Email" />
      <input id="txtPassword" type="password" required placeholder="Password" />
      <button id="btnLogin" class="button-is-link">Login</button>
      <button id="btnSignUp" class="button-is-info">Sign Up</button>
    </div>




    <script src="js/auth.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

## Auth.js

```
    (function() {
  // Initialize Firebase
  var config = {
    apiKey: 'API KEY',
    authDomain: 'DOMAIN',
    databaseURL: 'DATABASE',
    projectId: 'ID',
    storageBucket: 'BUCKET',
    messagingSenderId: 'ID'
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);

  const txtEmail = document.getElementById('txtEmail');
  const txtPassword = document.getElementById('txtPassword');
  const btnLogin = document.getElementById('btnLogin');
  const btnSignUp = document.getElementById('btnSignUp');

  btnLogin.addEventListener('click', e => {
    const email = txtEmail.value;
    const pass = txtPassword.value;
    const auth = firebase.auth();
    const promise = auth.signInWithEmailandPassword(email, pass);
    promise.catch(e => console.log('e.message'));
  });

  btnSignUp.addEventListener('click', e => {
    const email = txtEmail.value;
    const pass = txtPassword.value;
    const auth = firebase.auth();
    const promise = auth.createUserWithEmailandPassword(email, pass);
    promise.catch(e => console.log('e.message'));

    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChange(firebaseUser => {
      if (firebaseUser) {
        console.log('U are logged in');
      } else {
        console.log('Not logged in');
      }
    });
  });
})();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exact method name is `signInWithEmailAndPassword`, with an upper case "A" at And.

It is the same with `createUserWithEmailAndPassword`.

Comment: I got to say I checked that syntax quite a while and didn't catch the A. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

run given  below command,  Before execute make sure to  delete "package-lock.json"

> npm i @angular/fire@latest --save